# laravel5でメール送信をSMTP認証にした際のauth_modeの設定について

Tags: php, laravel

laravelでシステムを構築し、メールの配信部分をSMTP配信のサービスを利用して運用を考えております。
そちらのSMTP認証の設定がLOGINのみのサポートとなっており、laravelでauth_modeの設定が出来るのかどうか調べていたのですが、config/mail.phpには設定項目が無いようで、ネットで調べてみたもののいい情報が得られませんでした。

- 設定する方法があるのかどうか
- また初期設定はどのようになっているのか

ご教示頂けたらと思います。